# SwingのDocumentEventの追加について

Tags: java, swing

内部クラスを使って`DocumentEvent`を使いたいのですが、`addDocumentListener`の使い方がいまいちわかりません。どこを修正すべきでしょうか？ よろしくお願いします。

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

class CaesarFrame{
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField1, textField2;
    JButton button;
    JPanel panel1, panel2;
    JComboBox<Object> comboBox1;
    Object[] ob = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L'
            ,'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    Container contentPane;
    JLabel label;

    // Constructor
    CaesarFrame(){  
        frame = new JFrame("SwingLab");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 110);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        textField1 = new JTextField(20);
        textField2 = new JTextField(28);
        textField2.setEditable(false);
        button = new JButton("Code!");
        comboBox1 = new JComboBox<Object>(ob);
        label = new JLabel("Output:");
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.add(comboBox1);
        panel1.add(textField1);
        panel1.add(button);
        panel2.add(label);
        panel2.add(textField2);

        contentPane.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(panel2,BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        ActionListener buttonCode = new OkButtonActionListener();
        button.addActionListener(buttonCode);

        KeyAdapter key = new InputFieldKeyListener();
        textField1.addKeyListener(key);
        //この箇所がよくわかりません。
        KeyAdapter key2 = new InputFieldKeyListener();
        Document doc = ((DocumentEvent) key2).getDocument();
        doc.addDocumentListener((DocumentListener) key);

    }

    class InputFieldKeyListener extends KeyAdapter implements DocumentListener{
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char temp = e.getKeyChar();
            String ch =String.valueOf(temp);
            char offset = (char) comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            textField2.setText(Caesar.caesarCode(ch,offset));
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Changed");
            }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Inserted");
            }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Removed");
            }


    }



    private class OkButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String message = textField1.getText();
            char offset = (char) comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            textField2.setText(Caesar.caesarCode(message,offset));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [JTextField (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)の冒頭から引用:
>
> JTextComponentベースのコンポーネントでは、DocumentEvent経由でモデルからDocumentListenersに変更が送られます。DocumentEventは、必要に応じて、変更位置と変更の種類を提供します。この部分のコードは次のようになります。
>
> ```
> DocumentListener myListener = ??;
> JTextField myArea = ??;
> myArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(myListener);
> ```

とあるように、[JTextComponent#getDocument()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument--)メソッドを使用すると良さそうです。

```
//この箇所がよくわかりません。
//InputFieldKeyListener key2 = new InputFieldKeyListener();
// Document doc = ((DocumentEvent) key2).getDocument();
// doc.addDocumentListener((DocumentListener) key);
// DocumentEvent#getDocument()ではなく、JTextComponent#getDocument()を使うべき
textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(key);
```

**サンプルコード**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class CaesarFrameTest {
  Object[] ob = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'
    , 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
  };
  private final JComboBox<Object> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<>(ob);
  private final JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(20);
  private final JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(28);
  private final JButton button = new JButton("Code!");

  public Container makeUI() {
    textField2.setEditable(false);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Output:");
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    panel1.add(comboBox1);
    panel1.add(textField1);
    panel1.add(button);
    panel2.add(label);
    panel2.add(textField2);

    ActionListener buttonCode = new OkButtonActionListener();
    button.addActionListener(buttonCode);

    InputFieldKeyListener key = new InputFieldKeyListener();
    textField1.addKeyListener(key);

    //この箇所がよくわかりません。
    //InputFieldKeyListener key2 = new InputFieldKeyListener();
    // Document doc = ((DocumentEvent) key2).getDocument();
    // doc.addDocumentListener((DocumentListener) key);
    textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(key);

    Container contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
    return contentPane;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("SwingLab");
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new CaesarFrameTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(400, 110);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }

  class InputFieldKeyListener extends KeyAdapter implements DocumentListener {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char temp = e.getKeyChar();
      System.out.println(temp);
      String ch = String.valueOf(temp);
      Object offset = comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
      textField2.setText(String.format("%s %s", ch, offset));
      //char offset = (char) comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
      //textField2.setText(Caesar.caesarCode(ch,offset));
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("Inserted");
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("Removed");
    }


  }
  private class OkButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String message = textField2.getText();
      Object offset = comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
      //textField2.setText(Caesar.caesarCode(message,offset));
    }
  }
}
```